# UnicodeDecodeError only with cx_freeze

Tags: python, encoding, python-3.x, cx-freeze

I get the error: `"UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 7338: ordinal not in range(128)"` once I try to run the program after I freeze my script with cx_freeze.  If I run the Python 3 script normally it runs fine, but only after I freeze it and try to run the executable does it give me this error.  I would post my code, but I don't know exactly what parts to post so if there are any certain parts that will help just let me know and I will post them, otherwise it seems like I have had this problem once before and solved it, but it has been a while and I can't remember what exactly the problem was or how I fixed it so any help or pointers to get me going in the right direction will help greatly.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tell us exactly which version of Python on what platform.

Show the full traceback that you get when the error happens. Look at it yourself. What is the last line of your code that appears? What do you think is the `bytes` string that is being decoded? Why is the `ascii` codec being used??

Note that automatic conversion of `bytes` to `str` with a default codec (e.g. ascii) is NOT done by Python 3.x. So either you are doing it explicitly or cx_freeze is.

**Update** after further info in comments.

Excel does not save csv files in ASCII. It saves them in what MS calls "the ANSI codepage", which varies by locale. If you don't know what yours is, it is probably `cp1252`. To check, do this:

```
>>> import locale; print(locale.getpreferredencoding())
cp1252
```

If Excel did save files in ASCII, your offending `'\xa0'` byte would have been replaced by '?' and you would not be getting a UnicodeDecodeError.

Saving your files in `UTF-8` would need you to open your files with `encoding='utf8'` and would have the same problem (except that you'd get a grumble about 0xc2 instead of 0xa0).

You don't need to post all four of your csv files on the web. Just run this little script (untested):

```
import sys
for filename in sys.argv[1:]:
    for lino, line in enumerate(open(filename), 1):
        if '\xa0' in line:
            print(ascii(filename), lino, ascii(line))
```

The `'\xa0'` is a `NO-BREAK SPACE` aka `&nbsp;` ... you may want to edit your files to change these to ordinary spaces.

Probably you will need to ask on the cx_freeze mailing list to get an answer to why this error is happening. They will want to know the full traceback. Get some practice -- show it here.

By the way, "offset 7338" is rather large -- do you expect lines that long in your csv file? Perhaps something is reading all of your file ...

Comment: I am using python v3.1 on Windows, tried on bot x86 and 64.  I would show you the full traceback.  The last call of my code on the stack is the for loop for getting my data from a csv file: 'for row in DataReader:'.  I am not sure why ascii codec is being used, I am not explicitly using it, I have tried opening the 2 problem files in notepad and changing the encoding to UTF-8 and re-saving it because maybe excel saves in ascii encoding, still no help. so I guess that leaves cx_freeze using ascii which makes sense if the problem only appears after I freeze the script.  So how do I fix this?

Comment: @Brock S.: edit your question instead of adding new info in comments. *Show the full traceback*. Show how you are opening the input file.

Comment: This worked great! There were 2 lines in one file that had a &nbsp at then end of one of the cells and 1 line in another file that used a &nbsp instead of a space.  All I needed to do was get rid of those characters and replace one with a regular space.  This really confuses me as to why I just got this error now.  I have used these files before with frozen scripts the same way I am using it now.  I guess I will ask on the cx_freeze mailing list like you suggested to maybe see why this error showed up this time only.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

That error itself indicates that you have a character in a python string that isn't a normal ASCII character:

```
>>> b'abc\xa0'.decode('ascii')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 3: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I certainly don't know why this would only happen when a script is frozen. You could wrap the whole script in a `try`/`except` and manually print out all or part of the string in question.

EDIT: here's how that might look

```
try:
    # ... your script here
except UnicodeDecodeError as e:
    print("Exception happened in string '...%s...'"%(e.object[e.start-50:e.start+51],))
    raise
```

Comment: Ok update on the problem with a little more info. The problem occurs in the line 'for row in DataReader:' with DataReader being a csv reader object.  So to add to the strange effect that this error only occurs after I freeze, it also only occurs for my first 2 of 4 files I read data from at the beginning of my program.  I wrapped each for loop in a try/except and when the error occurred it happened at the beginning so it didn't pull any data from the csv file.  Any ideas?  I could somehow post all 4 csv files if you could tell me the difference between the first 2 and last 2 to make the error.

Comment: You'll want to print out the part of the string that's messing things up so you can figure out why (see my latest edit in the answer above). If it's not obvious right off what's happening and why, try to debug the script when it's processing the same part of the same string in the non-frozen version and check if the string itself has different characters, or something else is going on.

Answer (score 2):

## fix by set default coding:

```
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8")
```

Comment: From Python documentation on `sys.setdefaultencoding`: "This function is only intended to be used by the site module implementation and, where needed, by sitecustomize."

Answer (score 1):

Use `str.decode()` function for that lines. And also you can specify encoding like `myString.decode('cp1252')`.

Look also: http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/howto/unicode.html#unicode-howto

Comment: A plain `\xa0` by itself isn't valid UTF-8 either, it's most likely ISO 8859-1 or Windows-1252.

Comment: @Adam Rosenfield: He's on Windows, reading the result of Excel "save as CSV". Chance of ISO 8859-1 is <= 0 :)